# Time conversion Not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic time picker in my project. When I select the time picker it passes a value to the controller. For example when I select 09:00pm, the console shows 79200. If I select 07:00pm the console shows 68400. I want to convert the value to 12 hrs format. I have followed some steps, but it's not working for me.

My code:

```
var a = new Date($scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime*1000);
console.log(a);
var b = moment.utc(a).format("HH:mm");
console.log(b)
$scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime = val;
console.log(val);
//var yourDateObject = new Date();

var selectedTime = new Date();
var amPmHour = $filter('date')(selectedTime, 'hh');
console.log(amPmHour);
$scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(val*1000), 'hh:mma');
console.log($scope.time);
console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), ':', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'in UTC');
```

I tried the code above, but nothing is working. Below i have added my origional code:

```
$scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime = val;
    console.log(val);
    console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), ':', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'in UTC');
```

1. on the first console.log i am getting 68400,
2. for second  console log I am getting 68400 and the time is  19:00 in UTC. How to convert 12 hr format for the selected time?

Comment: `h % 12 || 12` and `h<12?'am':'pm'`, where `h` is 24hr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the result as a string. Here is a simple implementation with moment.js:

```
var secs = 68400;
console.log(moment().startOf('day').add(secs, 'seconds').format("h:mm a"));
```

Will output "7:00 pm"

See in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/D0ai2PpEhnuJkTYblW29?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can receive your 12Hrs format by using the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
var hours = new Date(68400000).getHours();    // 20 o'clock in milliseconds
hours = hours % 12;                           // Division by 12
hours = hours ? hours : 12;                   // the hour '0' should be '12'
console.log(hours)                            // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secs = 68400;
console.log(moment().startOf('day').add(secs, 'seconds').format("hh:mma"));
```

See i outputed as 07:00pm! So 07:00pm is called 12 hour clock